# Triple for-loop in a vector

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a simple numpy array (3xN) like:

```
v = np.array([[-3.33829, -3.42467, -3.53332],
   [-2.67681, -2.6082 , -3.49502],
   [-3.49497, -2.73177, -2.61499],
   [-2.76056, -3.57753, -2.67334],
   [-1.96801, -3.47521, -3.51974],
   [-1.25571, -2.69451, -3.45554],
   [-1.94568, -2.59504, -2.72568],
   [-1.28991, -3.47927, -2.73176],
   [-0.51201, -3.50684, -3.40448],
   [ 0.22398, -2.70244, -3.43421]])
```

Here, N = 10, but it is much larger than here (+500) in my real case. Each row is a point - Euclidean coordinate.

I would like to carry out:

[image]

where i, j and k indicate different rows from v.

How can I implement it on Python in a fast way?

Comment: 500 is no big deal. Is this performance critical? For loops go brrrr

Comment: this is 500^3 so it might be a big deal... 3 stands for 3 for loops = 125,000,000

Comment: check out [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). It is designed to handle cases such as this.

Comment: What would be the shape of the expected output in this case? I would assume `3XN` as per the equation?

Comment: Though it looks like euclidean distance, it's actually not differences between coordinates, but a difference between vectors. I might be wrong, but to me the equation suggests the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using numpy [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) operations:

```python
diffs = ((v[:, None] - v) ** 2).sum(-1)
d = np.exp(diffs + diffs[:, None]).sum((0, 1))
print(d)

# [3.08316899e+11 2.37020625e+07 4.05357364e+12 8.22697743e+08
#  8.85209202e+04 2.55340202e+05 7.33879459e+04 1.88175133e+05
#  8.10134295e+08 6.62122925e+12]
```

Even for an array of size 500, the result is computed in just a few seconds:

```python
%%time
v = np.random.rand(500, 3)
diffs = np.sum((v[:, None] - v) ** 2, -1)
d = np.exp(diffs + diffs[:, None]).sum((0, 1))

# CPU times: user 2.74 s, sys: 5.5 ms, total: 2.75 s
# Wall time: 2.75 s
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the equation suggests pairwise **vector** differences, and not squared distance between vectors.

[image]

The pairwise difference between N vectors will be N*N vectors.

Finally, I would assume since you are only reducing over `j` and `k` axes, the output vector is `(10,3)` and not `(10,)`. Do correct me if I am wrong.

```
import numpy as np

d = np.exp(((v[:,None]-v)**2)[:,None] + ((v[:,None]-v)**2)).sum((0,1))
print(d)

#### Stepwise breakdown
#v                           #i,3 -> 10,3
#diff = (v[:,None]-v)**2     #j,i,3 -> 10,10,3
#power = diff[:,None]+diff   #k,j,i,3 -> 10,10,10,3
#exp = np.exp(power)         #k,j,i,3 -> 10,10,10,3
#d = np.sum(exp,(1,2))       #i,3 -> 10,3
```

```
array([[4.38558108e+11, 2.11224470e+02, 2.08153285e+02],
       [6.10332697e+09, 2.42309774e+02, 2.00079357e+02],
       [1.37237360e+12, 2.11552094e+02, 2.32739462e+02],
       [9.98934092e+09, 2.51158071e+02, 2.16562340e+02],
       [1.77827910e+08, 2.22151678e+02, 2.05163797e+02],
       [1.91234145e+08, 2.19457894e+02, 1.92858561e+02],
       [1.63391357e+08, 2.46419838e+02, 2.04498335e+02],
       [1.67512751e+08, 2.23119070e+02, 2.03232700e+02],
       [8.45322705e+09, 2.30065042e+02, 1.85024981e+02],
       [1.14468558e+12, 2.17683864e+02, 1.89388595e+02]])
```

---

Benchmark -

```
%%timeit
np.exp(((v[:,None]-v)**2)[:,None] + ((v[:,None]-v)**2)).sum((0,1))
# 21.2 s ± 3.27 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: "the equation suggests pairwise vector differences, and not squared distance between vectors."

Indeed, the squared differences are squared distance between vectors. The square means an inner product. So, the result should be an array (10,).

Thanks for your comment.